# Extension operator maps which fractional Sobolev space to $W^{p,s}(R)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fractional-calculus

Let us assume we have the following extension operator:
$$
\operatorname{ext}_R^\sigma u=
\begin{cases}
 u(x) & \text{if }x \in (0,T)\\ 
 u(0) & \text{if }x \in(0,T)^c.
\end{cases}
$$ We assume the fractional Sobolev space $W^{p,s}$, $s\in (0,1)$.
 For the definition of the norm see p. 13 of the book by Giovanni Leoni, *[A first course in fractional Sobolev spaces](https://books.google.de/books/about/A_First_Course_in_Fractional_Sobolev_Spa.html?id=lh2_EAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&gboemv=1&redir_esc=y)*, Graduate Studies in Mathematics 229, AMS, (2023), [MR4567945](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=4567945), [Zbl 1517.46001](https://zbmath.org/1517.46001).

**My question** is how do we define a space $W$ such that $\operatorname{ext}_R^\sigma\in W^{p,s}(R)$?

I tried $u\in W^{p,s}(0,T)$ but this is impossible because the boundary term $\int_{(0,T)^c}u(0) \, dx$ is not finite and we also will get the other two terms when we calculate the fractional seminorm. How do we get rid of these boundary terms?  I appreciate if you can provided any clues.